# How do I insert data on radio button click - jquery/php/mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, radio-button

After php and mysql outputs a list of data in a table with radio buttons, dropdown boxes and text boxes for each row from the database, I'd like to be able to AJAX update the database onclick of radio button, dropdown boxes or entry of text. This is what I have...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<?php
require_once 'config.php';

echo '<table style="margin:0 auto;">
<tr>

</tr>';

$sql = "SELECT id, address, suburb, lat, lng, day, date, time FROM addresses";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


      echo '<tr>

      <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">'. $row["address"].' '. $row["suburb"].'</span> <button style="float:right;" type="button">Go</button><br><br>
        H<input type="radio" name="home['. $row["id"].']" value="1"/>
        NH<input type="radio" name="home['. $row["id"].']" value="2"/>
        <select style="padding:1.4px;">
          <option></option>
          <option>Mo</option>
          <option>Tu</option>
          <option>We</option>
          <option>Th</option>
          <option>Fr</option>
          <option>Sa</option>
          <option>Su</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="time1" size="2">
        <select style="padding:1.4px;">
          <option></option>
          <option>Mo</option>
          <option>Tu</option>
          <option>We</option>
          <option>Th</option>
          <option>Fr</option>
          <option>Sa</option>
          <option>Su</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="time2" size="2"><br>
        <input style="width:100%; margin-top:5px;" type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Add note">
        <br><br>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>


    </tr>';

    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo '</table>';

$conn->close();

?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var home = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
             url:"updateaddress.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{home:home},
        });
   });
});
</script>
```

```html
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
$home = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['home']);



if(isset($_POST["home"])) {
  $sql = "UPDATE addresses SET home='$home' WHERE id=$id";
  if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){

    } else {
      echo "error" . $sql . "<br>".$conn->error;
    }
  }



mysqli_close($conn);
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
exit;
?>
```

I can't figure out what I need to do to get this to work. 
Please help.

Comment: What error are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the id of the row in to that ajax page...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<?php
require_once 'config.php';

echo '<table style="margin:0 auto;">
<tr>

</tr>';

$sql = "SELECT id, address, suburb, lat, lng, day, date, time FROM addresses";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


      echo '<tr>

      <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">'. $row["address"].' '. $row["suburb"].'</span> <button style="float:right;" type="button">Go</button><br><br>
        H<input type="radio" name="home['. $row["id"].']" id="'. $row["id"].'" value="1"/>
        NH<input type="radio" name="home['. $row["id"].']" id="'. $row["id"].'" value="2"/>
        <select style="padding:1.4px;">
          <option></option>
          <option>Mo</option>
          <option>Tu</option>
          <option>We</option>
          <option>Th</option>
          <option>Fr</option>
          <option>Sa</option>
          <option>Su</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="time1" size="2">
        <select style="padding:1.4px;">
          <option></option>
          <option>Mo</option>
          <option>Tu</option>
          <option>We</option>
          <option>Th</option>
          <option>Fr</option>
          <option>Sa</option>
          <option>Su</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="time2" size="2"><br>
        <input style="width:100%; margin-top:5px;" type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Add note">
        <br><br>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>


    </tr>';

    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo '</table>';

$conn->close();

?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var home = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
             url:"updateaddress.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{home:home,id:id},
        });
   });
});
</script>
```

```html
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
$home = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['home']);



if(isset($_POST["home"])) {
  $sql = "UPDATE addresses SET home='$home' WHERE id=$id";
  if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){

    } else {
      echo "error" . $sql . "<br>".$conn->error;
    }
  }



mysqli_close($conn);
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Sarvan! How do I add the values of the dropdown box on change? I added this: $(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="select"]').change(function(){
        var nhd1 = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
             url:"updateaddress.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{nhd1:nhd1,id:id,},
        });
   });
});

Comment: I have checked the above one. Please use below one.
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('select').change(function(){ 
  var nhd1 = $(this).val(); 
  console.log(nhd1);
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
  $.ajax({ 
   url:"updateaddress.php", 
   method:"POST", 
   data:{nhd1:nhd1,id:id,}, 
  }); 
 }); 
});

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I still can't get it to work. I've added this: $nhd1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nhd1']); and using this query: $sql = "UPDATE addresses SET nhd1='$nhd1' WHERE id=$id"; I think I need to change something in the select box output? Please help

Comment: Which one ? for the select box jquery.

Comment: ok I just figured it out. I had to do this:   if(isset($_POST["nhd1"])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE addresses SET nhd1='$nhd1' WHERE id=$id"; Thanks so much for your help!